# Strategy for storing private keys used in an embedded device

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, appsec, key-management, storage, docker

I am developing an embedded device using a bootloader. This means that the device will store in its flash an encryption key for decrypting update packages and an ECC public key for verifying update signatures. For this, the process needs the encryption key and ECC private key as files for compilation of the firmware and update packages. The compilation is triggered from a GitLab CI pipeline and I am now trying to figure out best strategies for storing the keys in a secure way but still being able to automate the compilation step.

I have come up with the following strategy and was wondering if it makes any sense:

1. Store keys as encrypted files in the physical build server that is running GitLab CI jobs
2. Store decryption key for the encrypted files in the GitLab project as a CI/CD variable
3. GitLab triggers compilation job in the build server inside a Docker container that decrypts the keys before compilation

This would require an attacker to have access both to the GitLab project's variables and the encrypted files in the build server. To my understanding the Docker container has pretty good isolation from the rest of the host system. I should also mention that I am using my company's GitLab instance that is not publicly available to the internet.

What are some obvious weaknesses and should I approach this problem from a completely different angle?

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt firmware updates? Signing them is enough.

Comment: Your problem isn't "where do I store the decryption key in Gitlab" but "where do I store it in the device?" and the answer is, usually, you don't. You only need the public key for signature verification. There's really no point in encrypting the firmware; you can't prevent somebody from reading it anyhow (either by extracting the decryption key from a device, or just installing the image and viewing the decrypted files in flash). Ignore encryption, and just sign it. Simplifies things a lot, and nothing of value is lost.

Comment: Boy this comment section is wild.  Don't encrypt firmware updates?  I want to know what corporation allows their security professionals to run around with that opinion.  Make my job 100x easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be really secure, you encrypt the firmware with a random key generated in your CI pipeline, not persisted, and the CI call an HSM to wrap the key with a KEK and ship the wrapped key with the encrypted firmware (they KEK is the key in the micro controller). Your signature key should also be in a HSM (which can be as small as an USB one).

With that in place you got good insurance that your keys won't leak, but the compromission of your CI platform still means an attacker could use the key and sign whatever (and decrypt previous firmwares). Future firmware would not be compromised OTOH as it would be encrypted with new keys, and signature keys should be rotated too.

Answer (score 0):

Professionally I've seen secrets managed as files on the CI server.  With well groomed access controls on a server which isn't exposed to the broader internet this is okay.  Security is all about threat models though, so if that makes you nervous...

The other option is a secrets manager.  I think Gitlab is friendly with HcVault.  The other option I hear a lot is AWS Secrets Manager.  Any competent cloud probably has a competing product.  Files on iron isn't really scale-able as the operation grows to multiple servers or the cloud.  Also, secrets managers correctly configured likely exceed the security stance of any file based storage (no matter how many levels of indirection on where the key is stored).